# How to delete title bar while also keeping the window resizable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to hide the title bar while keeping the window resizable, `this.ControlBox = false;` didn't work
and `this.FormBorderStyle = 0` hid the title bar but the window isn't resizable, is there any other way?